# Unable to get classified dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-injection, dependencies, jt400

In this
[maven repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/jt400/jt400/9.5/)
I'd like to use the _jdk8 classification.

But when I'm using the gradle dependecy declared like this:

```
compile('net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.5:jdk8')
```

It tries to get the file like this:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/jt400/jt400/9.5/jt400-9.5-jdk8.jar

So it's using a dash in the classification instead of a subscore like they have used in the repo, does anyone know how to get it to use subscore?

Error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find jt400-jdk8.jar (net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.5).
  Searched in the following locations:
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the name wrong in the repository:

the classification was supposed to be `jt400_jdk8` not only `jdk8` that means that a working dependency injection will be:
`compile('net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.5:jt400_jdk8')`